# Node.js Javascript and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I am trying to manipulate a string by splitting it into two.

**my js**

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var href1,href;
var str = "https://google.co.in/search?q=okay"+"+google";

request(str, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var a = $('.r a');
    href = a.attr('href');
    href1="https://google.co.in"+href;
      var href


      console.log(href1);

        request(href1, function (error, response, html){

           if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var a1 = $('ol li a');
    var href2 = a1.attr('href'); 
               var href3 = href2.indexOf("/48");
               var href4=href3.substring(0,20);

           console.log(href4);

           }
        });
  }
});
```

it gives a TypeError at the line where i use the substring function :

> Undefined is not a function.

However, href3 returns an integer and that is fine. So, I know href3 is not empty or undefined.

How can I fix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to call a String function from a Number. Href3 will not have the substring function because indexOf returns a Number.

The line:

```
var href4=href3.substring(0,20);
```

Should probably be:

```
 var href4=href2.substring(0,20);
```

Comment: COuld you also tell me now that I have js file ready, with express and cheerio modules running via nodejs, How do I actually make this available on the internet?

Comment: I mean, uploading HTML, CSS and JS, in the usual manner or do I need to add node_modules directory too. How?

Comment: That's a very large topic. You have several options available to you. The easiest I think would be to use Heroku / AWS / Azure to get started with a simple website solution.

Comment: I'll see that. Thanks.

Comment: But yes you will need the node_modules folder as this provides all the dependencies for you application. You can either deploy the dependencies or get a deploy process to run npm install on your server.